# EntityFramework ExecuteSqlCommand não aceitando parametro

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou executando o ExecuteSqlCommand.

Com o modo correto, **com parâmetro** não funciona:

```
var SQL = "update POSTOFFICE set Status = 1 where name = '@url'";
dbMailEnable.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(SQL, new SqlParameter("@url", EP.Cliente.Url.Trim().ToLower()));
```

**Sem parâmetro** funciona!

```
var SQL = "update POSTOFFICE set Status = 1 where name = '" + EP.Cliente.Url.Trim().ToLower() + "'";
dbMailEnable.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(SQL);
```

Porém sem parâmetro não é recomendável, SQL injection, etc. alias no help do Visual Studio nem constava que era possível assim.

***O Que fazer?***

OBS: Estou tendo que utilizar esse comando pois o database é de terceiros e não tem chaveprimária então não consegui fazer via Model.

Comment: tente fazer `var param = EP.Cliente.Url.Trim().ToLower(); dbMailEnable.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(SQL, new SqlParameter("@url",param);`

Comment: Posso direcionar uma segunda resposta usando o `Database` e não a `Connection`, mas preciso de detalhes do erro.

Answer (score 4):

Se a ideia é usar como ADO.NET, você pode [obter a `DbConnection` do contexto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.connection(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Database.Connection) e executar o comando usando `SqlParameters` normalmente:

```
using (var connection = dbMailEnable.Database.Connection as SqlConnection) // Não tem problema ~neste caso~ porque o Entity Framework garante uma SqlConnection pra você. 
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("update POSTOFFICE set Status = 1 where name = '@url'", connection);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@url", EP.Cliente.Url.Trim().ToLower()));
    var registrosAfetados = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: existe alguma vantagem? é mais rápido?

Comment: É quase a mesma coisa. Tem a vantagem de você ter controle total sobre o que está sendo executado, como é no ADO.NET.

Comment: cannont convert from 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Faltou o cast.